# Alert box with a <select> in it

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'd like to ask the user to choose among a few possibility but without breaking the style of my page. So I'd like to prompt an alert box or something like that BUT with a dropdown list () in it.

1. Is it possible?
2. If so how?

Comment: alert are ugly, cant you use modal ? from angular bootstrap

Comment: fiddle or code that you tried?

Comment: There are no native popups with selects, you'll have to use a modal.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation

[Official Example](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal)

Add angular-bootstrap.js in your project, and  'ui.bootstrap' in your module

in HTML

```
<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                <a ng-click="selected.item = item">{{ item }}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        Selected: <b>{{ selected.item }}</b>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</script>

<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('lg')">Large modal</button>
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('sm')">Small modal</button>
<div ng-show="selected">Selection from a modal: {{ selected }}</div>
```

JS

```
var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

$scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

$scope.open = function (size) {

var modalInstance = $modal.open({
  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
  controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
  size: size,
  resolve: {
    items: function () {
      return $scope.items;
    }
  }
});

modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
  $scope.selected = selectedItem;
}, function () {
  $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
});
};
};

// Please note that $modalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $modal service used above.

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.selected = {
    item: $scope.items[0]
  };

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
};
```